# How to print sample predictions of an Estimator using ValidationMonitor?

Tags: tensorflow

Consider the following common sample code to fit an estimator while validating `every_n_steps`:

```
  validation_metrics = {"accuracy": tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy,
                        "precision": tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision,
                        "recall": tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall,
                        "mean_abs_error": tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_absolute_error}

  validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(
      input_fn=input_fn_eval,
      every_n_steps=FLAGS.eval_every,
      metrics=validation_metrics,
      early_stopping_rounds=5000,
      early_stopping_metric="loss",
      early_stopping_metric_minimize=True)

  estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=None, monitors=[validation_monitor])
```

**Is it possible to print some random samples from the validation set?** I want to ensure that the model generate reasonable results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can write your own `Monitor` which does this. Look at the implementation of the `ValidationMonitor` to see how to extend it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433655/whats-the-best-way-to-print-some-samples-of-the-predicted-results-during-traini