# What's the best way to print some samples of the predicted results during training of the model?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to ask the model to predict the output for some random samples during the learning process. Currently, I built a class which derived from `tf.contrib.learn.monitors.EveryN` and overwrite `every_n_step_end` as follows:

```
def every_n_step_end(self, step, outputs):
  # evaluate the model on the validation set
  self._estimator.evaluate(
      input_fn=input_fn_eval,
      metrics=validation_metrics,
      steps=None)
  # generate some random samples
  for _ in range(FLAGS.num_samples):
    input_sample, output_sample, label = random.choice(validation_set)
    prob = self._estimator.predict(input_fn=lambda: get_features(input_sample, output_sample))
    print("{}:{}:{}:{}".format(input_sample, output_sample, prob[0, 0], label))
```

The problem is that is each iteration, `predict` function load the model from checkpoints and etc. **Is it the proper way?**

Answer (score 0):

`predict` method get an input function(`input_fn`) to preprocess and feed data into your models. So it's easy to create an input function and then pass it to `predict` method to get a list of predicted probabilities. See [Building Input Functions with tf.contrib.learn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/input_fn/index.html), for more information about writing input_fn function.